# Changing current directory with a bash script?

Tags: bash

I was wondering if it's possible to change directory of a shell from a bash script, but keep the directory change persistent to more than just the subshell.

I'm aware that when you run `cd` inside a bash script the directory will only change inside the subshell, and when you get back out you'll return to whatever directory you were in.

However, I want to make a command to bring me to certain directories. I could use an alias, but there are a lot of subdirectories that I would have to make an alias for..

Comment: Only if you source the script, rather than execute it.

Comment: Unless your `source` such a script, you can't make the changes reflect in the parent shell

Comment: So make a function.

Comment: This surely must be a dup?

Comment: just type "bash" after your "cd" command

Answer (score 1):

No, scripts are executed in a separate shell, which doesn't affect its ancestors. But you could use a function, which takes arguments, and so is more flexible than alias. Another option is sourcing files with `source` or its equivalent `.`, but that doesn't accept arguments. Still, it affects the current shell. You might combine the two and put functions in a file that you'd source and then use the functions in the current process.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for something like the `CDPATH` shell variable.

The `CDPATH` variable acts like `PATH` but for the `cd` command.

Setting with something like

```
CDPATH=".:~:~/projects:~/music"
```

would allow you to say

```
cd ricky_martin
```

anywhere, and it would go through the `:`-separated directory paths in the `$CDPATH` value in order until it found a subdirectory called `ricky_martin` somewhere (possibly `~/music/ricky_martin`) and then `cd` there.

Likewise

```
cd world_domination
```

may take you to `~/projects/world_domination` if there is such a subdirectory.  If `world_domination` also existed in the current directory, this directory would be selected first as it occurs earlier in `$CDPATH` (the dot in the first position).

It would also be allowed to do

```
cd proj1/tests
```

from anywhere to get to `~/projects/proj1/tests` if such a directory existed (with the above `$CDPATH` value, unless `proj/tests` did not exist in the current directory or in your home directory).

Note that the `CDPATH` shell variable should not be exported as that may seriously confuse some scripts.

The `CDPATH` variable is documented in the `bash` manual (`man bash`):

> `CDPATH`
>
> The search path for the `cd` command.  This is a colon-separated
>                 list of directories in which the shell looks for destination
>                 directories specified by the `cd` command.  A sample value is
>                 `".:~:/usr"`.